# trainings/teaching courses about (a suitable preposition)

Tags: prepositions

I want to say that the theme of trainings/teaching courses for staff is personal development. These courses are dedicated to the theme "Personal Development".

Staff of a company learn how to develop or improve their personal skills and competencies.

IS it possible to use the preposition 'about' instead of the word 'theme'?

> trainings/teaching courses about personal development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would pick the preposition **on**:

> (training/teaching) courses **on** personal development

And, per FumbleFinger's comment below, the words "training\teaching" are excessive here. The sense of "the pupils will be taught personal development" would be implied by the simple form:

> Courses **on** personal development.

Or, shorter:

> Personal development courses.

Comment: There will be an abbreviation instead of 'personal development'. I am not sure whether it will look good with the preposition 'about' or 'on'.

Comment: @Humbulani: Hm.. But I guess the sentence "Teaching courses about PD" would also look not very natural. You might mention this point, that the sentence will use an abbreviation, in your question. With "Teaching courses about PD", I would think PD is some kind of disease or disorder.

Comment: With the particular referent 'personal development', I could live with ***for***. But usually, *training/teaching courses* are courses concerned with *training/teaching* anyway. If we take a different discipline, *teaching courses on biology*, I don't see how *any* preposition will result in a "normal" designation. Either it's *a teaching course* or it's *a course on biology*. Or more likely, just *a biology course* - and by the same token, *a PD course*.

Comment: Thanks.  By the way, one of upvotes for the answer is mine.  :) So, I don't need 'teaching' here. But, besides courses, training and seminars should also be used in my context. In addition, it is another discipline in the form of the abbreviation. I cannot mention it for reasons of privacy.

Comment: "on" is the most idiomatic choice, given your description, i.e. improving interpersonal skills".  With university courses, one very frequently sees "Biology course" but one would see "Personal Development Workshop" far less often than "Workshop on Personal Development".